# bug in cv2 on pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

so here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
#load data
data_directory = r"C:\Users\ikon\PycharmProjects\LogisticRegression\dataset\CnicData"
CATEGORIES = ['Cnic', 'noCnic']
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(data_directory,category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),
                               cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        IMG_SIZE = 50
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()
        break
```

my issue is whenever i use cv2.resize or .imread the error it gives is `Cannot find reference 'imread' in '__init__.py'` or ```Cannot find reference 'resize ' in '**init**.py'````

i tried uninstalling and installing the library again but it does not work.
actually i was trying to resize the image using IMG_SIZE but i saw that as soon as i output the picture it is not pixelated as it should be due to the given size
kindly let me know if there is any missing information

Comment: Could you execute in terminal `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"` ?

Comment: output is 4.6.0

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych no, the error is gives is the following
``` 
ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2
```

Comment: Do you update new version for pycharm?